# Why two instance of an app shares the same signalr connection?

Tags: wpf, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Sorry for my english:

I have developed an app (wpf) to test a signalr server, but I realized that when I launch 2 instances of the app, and connect with different user to each one of them, they both receive the response from the server when I send "hello" message from *one* client.

Is it normal behaviuor?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set the service to have multiple users or single user at a time and create a communication channel between the user and service so that the transmitted information is send to the user who requested it and not to all users.   **btw This is not the way to ask a question here. Please read** http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: first my stupid error . I was calling  `Clients.All.hello(message + " from server"); ` instead of  `Clients.Caller.hello(message + " from server");` 
- second if I create multiple signalr hub connection in the same thread only the last receive message from the server 
but in different threads it works as expected ,